# Display storage image on excel file

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using this package to generate excel documents with Laravel: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel then showing storage image.

Laravel excel file not display storage image how to display storage image my code is.

foreach($order['details'] as $value){

```
    $test_processes = DB::table('test_processes')->join('process_items', 'test_processes.item_id', '=', 'process_items.id')->select('process_items.name','process_items.image')->where('test_id','=',$value->test_id)->get();

    $order_id = $value->order_id;
    $data[] = array(
        'parameter'   => $value['parameter'],
        'state'       => $value['state'],
        'method_type' => $value['method'],
        'method'      => $value['test_method'],
        'sampling'   => '',
        'Analysis'  => '',
        'quantity'  =>  $value['quantity']
    );

        foreach($test_processes as $item){
            $data[0][$item->name] = $item->name.'  '.$item->image.'<td><img src="'.$item->image.'" /></td>';
        }
    }

    Excel::create('job_pack', function($excel) use($data,$order_id){
        $excel->sheet('Sheet1', function($sheet) use($data,$order_id) {
            $head = array(
                'Parameter',
                'State',
                'Method type',
                'Test Method',
                'Sampling',
                'Analysis',
                'quantity',
                'Kit && Image'
            );

        $sheet->fromArray($head, null, 'A1', false, false);
        $r = 2;

        foreach($data as $val){
            $sheet->row($r,$val);
            $r++;
        }
        });
    })->store('xls', storage_path('excel/'.$order_id));
```